# SED and REGEX extraction and rejecting if pattern not found

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, regular-expression

In the SED command, I want to remove everything that comes after 2000_SOMENAME also if possible want to give an error if that format is not found.

For example, if the file name is `ITALY_2022_BEST1FRIENDS2_ROME.txt` . I only want `2022_BEST1FRIENDS2`
if that pattern is not found I want to give an error in the shell script.

`username=$(find . -iname '*.txt' | sed -e 's/.*_\([0-9]\{4\}_[0-9|A-z]*\).*/\1/i' | sort - | uniq -ui |tr -d '\n')`

The previous question and more info here: [Extracting a partial part from filename using SED](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704438/extracting-a-partial-part-from-filename-using-sed)
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, it probably makes more sense to use `grep -o` rather than sed, because grep will exit with an error if it finds no results. (The `-o` makes it only return the matched portion and not the whole line.)

The tricky thing is that you're piping to other commands, and you want to preserve that exit status in the case of an error.

If using bash, you could get the pipe to fail if any component fails with `set -o pipefail` (set it back with `set +o pipefail` afterwards to reset it if you want).

There may be similar methods for other shells.

```
set -o pipefail
username="$(find . -iname '*.txt' | grep -o -i '[0-9]\{4\}_[0-9A-Z]*' | sort - | uniq -ui |tr -d '\n')"
# get the exit status of the previous command
pipeexit="$?"
set +o pipefail
if [[ "$pipeexit" != 0 ]] ; then
    echo "username not found" >&2
    # line below quits the script; remove if you don't want that
    exit "$pipeexit"
fi
```

I followed your lead in making the pattern case insensitive (`-i` to grep; you had `i` in your sed command), and left the rest of the commands in the pipe unmodified: I assume you had a reason for them. (Though the `tr` command seems suspect; why mash all the results together on one line?)

You might also consider a simpler method to check for an "error": just checking if the `$username` variable is empty, which it would be if there were no grep results (but of course also if no .txt files were found by find, etc.; not sure if you wanted that ...).

```
username="$(find . -iname '*.txt' | grep -o -i '[0-9]\{4\}_[0-9A-Z]*' | sort - | uniq -ui |tr -d '\n')"
if [ -z "$username" ] ; then
    echo "username not found" >&2
    exit "$pipeexit"
fi
```

Which would work in other shells most likely...

Comment: But the issue I keep having is if there is say a year that is greater than 4 characters due to user input error it should be invalid. Only take an answer when it is XXXX_ANYCHARACTER - where the XXXX represents any number.

Comment: How do you want to guard against that? Should the character right before the pattern need to be _? `username="$(find . -iname '*.txt' |grep -o -i '_[0-9]\{4\}_[0-9A-Z]*' | sed 's/^_//' | sort - | uniq -ui |tr -d '\n' )"`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @frabjous. That is exactly what I was looking to do. I will try to implement this into my bigger code and see if it works. In my sample script, it does exactly what I wanted. Could you explain the sed '^_//' part? and the -i in the grep checks for case sensitivity?

Comment: Yes the `-i` is for case insensitivity; I only put that in because you had `i` at the end of your sed substitution in the original; take it out if you don't want it. The new grep pattern starts with _ and so _ is at the start of the results, but if I understand you right, you don't want the starting _ in the results, so sed `s/^_//` just removes them.

Comment: Gotcha! Would it be possible to store that username if it is a folder name? For example a folder name in a similar way but I only want to extract that particular part and store it in a variable. Unzipping a folder but it has multiple structures for me to find a text file. However I could take the folder name as variable and use that for the search and trim it? Instead of txt.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a really hard time understanding what you're asking. Do you mean that instead of starting from a file `ITALY_2022_BEST1FRIENDS2_ROME.txt` listed by `find . -iname '*.txt'`, you'd have a folder named `ITALY_2022_BEST1FRIENDS2_ROME/`' or something like that and want to extract the same part from it? Just change the find command appropriately, e.g., `find . -type d` maybe? Not sure because your question is very unclear.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. But hope this explains it better. I am looking at folder names 2022_BESTFRIEND1_ROME >> I which there are multiple folders one of them has a text file name ITALY_2022_BESTFRIEND1_ROME. So what I am saying is I would have to be in multiple folder directory to make the username command work? If so could I store the folder name as variable then trim that name according to the code above? How would I do that.

Comment: Sorry I still have absolutely no clue what you are asking.