# Validating only four digits using SED

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

In the SED command, I only want the SED to work if there are `SOMETHING_4DigitsHereOnly_SOMETHING2`.

For example, if the file name is `ITALY_2022_BEST1FRIENDS2_ROME.txt` . I only want `2022_BEST1FRIENDS2` but also if it is named `ITALY_202345_BEST1FRIENDS2_ROME.txt` then it should give an error because it is not 4 digits it is more than 4.
if that pattern is not found I want to give an error in the shell script.

`username=$(find . -iname '*.txt' | sed -e 's/.*_\([0-9]\{4\}_[0-9|A-z]*\).*/\1/i' | sort - | uniq -ui |tr -d '\n')`

grep code that does the same but gives an error if file doesn't match thanks to user @frabjous:

```
read filename
set -o pipefail
filename_trimmed=$(echo $filename | grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}_[0-9|A-z]*' -i | sort - | uniq -ui |tr -d '\n')
# get the exit status of the previous command
pipeexit="$?"
set +o pipefail
if [[ "$pipeexit" != 0 ]] ; then
    echo "FILENAME not found" >&2
    # line below quits the script; remove if you don't want that
    exit "$pipeexit"
fi
echo trimmed mmc is  $filename_trimmed
```

The previous question and more info here: [Extracting a partial part from filename using SED](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704438/extracting-a-partial-part-from-filename-using-sed)
[SED and REGEX extraction and rejecting if pattern not found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/705349/sed-and-regex-extraction-and-rejecting-if-pattern-not-found?noredirect=1&lq=1)
Thank you!!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend bash for general text processing, but it's capable of manipulating (and validating) filenames. Are you opposed to a shell/bash-based solution?

Comment: The code that I have has #!/bin/bash which is the reason I am using bash commands. I'm new to this so understand everything with a google search right now!

Answer (score 0):

I find it much harder to understand sed speak.  I prefer awk for most things.

Given that, one solution to your problem is the following script which, as you can see, can make the logic more explicit to follow (*a key to code maintainability if you only revisit that code at long intervals*):

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                               

BASE=`basename "$0" ".sh" `
TMP="/tmp/tmp.$$.${BASE}"               ; rm -f "${TMP}"

START=`pwd`
REPORT="${START}/${BASE}.report"    ; rm -f "${REPORT}"

if [ -n "${1}" ]
then
    EVAL_DIR="$1"
else
    EVAL_DIR="."
fi


############
#find "${EVAL_DIR}" -iname '*.txt' -print | sed 's+\.txt$++'
#exit 0
############

find "${EVAL_DIR}" -iname '*.txt' -print | sed 's+\.txt$++' | sort |
    awk -F _ -v suf="txt" '\
        function is_integer(x) {
            if( index(x, ".") != 0 ){
                return 0 ;
            } ;
            if( x + 0 == x && int(x) == x ){
                return 1 ;
            }else{
                return 0 ;
            } ;
        }
        ! is_integer($2) {
            printf("#ERROR|%s."suf"\n", $0 ) ;
        }
        length($2) == 4 {
            for( i=2 ; i < NF ; i++ ){
                printf("%s_", $i ) ;
            } ;
            print $NF ;
        } ;
        length($2) != 4 {
            printf("#ERROR|%s."suf"\n", $0 ) ;
        }' >"${REPORT}"

exit 0
```